# Easy question: Multiple random variables vs. product of probability spaces

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I never had a course in probability theory and the definitions we work with are quite informal, so I am a little bit confused about the difference between "multiple" random variables and the notion of a random variable in a product probability space.

So in particular, we had the concept of negative correlation, where we defined $X,Y$ (two random variables) to be negatively correlated iff $E[XY] \leq E[X] E[Y]$. 
Somehow, this seems only to make sense, if $X$ and $Y$ are from the same probability space, thus $X \colon \Omega \rightarrow W_X$ and $Y\colon \Omega \rightarrow W_Y$ for some $\Omega$, and are interested in two different quantities $X$ and $Y$ concerning the *same* random experiment?
Otherwise, I would not see any sense in computing $E[XY]$?

Then, we had Azuma's inequality. There we considered a product space $(\Omega, P)$ of $N$ probability spaces $(\Omega_1, P_1), \dotsc, (\Omega_N, P_N)$ and look at a random variable $X \colon \Omega \rightarrow W_X$. Now $X$ is a vector of random variables.

So, I do not really understand what this is, where the differences are and when we do apply the one and when the other. And if negative correlation can also be defined for a product space? Could you give me some intuitive examples to see the difference between these two settings? Sorry for the possibly too easy questions, but I think in informal courses about probability, one never really teaches that, so this is really a pity.

Is it correct that the first one is the same random experiment and two different quantities, and the second one are different random experiments with some quantities.

So, let us assume that I draw two coins independently. This now belongs to the second example, if I let $\Omega=\{head, tail\}$. But it could also belong to the first example, if I let $\Omega = \{ (head, head), (head, tail), (tail, head), (tail, tail)\}$. Or not?